# Ordering output files

Tags: regex, unix, file-io, awk

I have a file containing a large number of protein sequences. Each sequence is headed up by an initial "protein ID number" (GI number for those that know). I am using a awk command that allows me to print between two regular expressions. Using this, I can enter a list of GI numbers into one regex field where each GI number is separated by a "|". The second regex is a regex I added in after every protein, allowing me to perform the awk function (ABC123). 
Therefore the code I am using is as follows

```
awk '/GI1|GI2|GI3|GI4|GIX.../,/ABC123/' database.txt > output.txt
```

As you can see from the above code, I am searching within database.txt and writing a new file. The problem is, when I open output.txt the list of GI's is in the wrong order. In output.txt I need them to occur in the same order as they occur in the first regex field i.e

```
GI1
GI2
GI3...
```

Instead, they occur in the order which they are found in database.txt, so in output.txt they look all jumbled i.e

```
Gi3
GI4
GI1
GI2
GI5
```

Does anyone know how I can get the list of GIs in the output file to match the same order as the list of GIs I input in the 1st regex field?

Comment: I presume they are not always in the same order as `sort` would produce then, if you did `sort < output.txt` ?

Comment: As in, add `sort` before output.txt? like `...database.txt > sort output.txt`

Comment: It would be `awk '....' database.txt | sort > output.txt`

Comment: Presumably your data blocks are multiple lines, so it is not going to be easy to make `sort` sort them correctly (because it sorts by lines).  The regex imposes no ordering; it simply recognizes alternatives.  Your best bet is probably Perl (or Python), reading the data and retaining the proteins that are wanted in memory as it encounters them.  It can then print them out in the desired order.  Failing that (or if you must use `awk`), then you'll need to have `awk` save the data in memory in appropriate data structures and then sort and print the data when you've collected all the information.

Comment: Only use ranges `/start/,/end/` if you want to get the block from the first start to the last end in the file, not for cases like yours where you want to find multiple blocks in a file as in those cases it makes trivial jobs slightly briefer but even slightly more complicated jobs much more difficult or requiring a complete re-write. Use `'/start/{f=1} f; /end/{f=0}/'` instead. Now - post some sample input and expected output of your awk command so we can help you do it right.

Comment: Continuing what @EdMorton said you especially don't want to use a range if it means modifying your input to support it. If you take my answer to your previous question and add `{d[n]=d[n] ORS $0; n++}` to it and grab the max value of `GI###` in the gi matching action you should be able to do what you want with a loop in an `END` action.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command,

```
awk '/GI1|GI2|GI3|GI4|GIX.../,/ABC123/' database.txt | sort -k1.3,1.3 > output.txt
```

Now your output.txt contains the sorted list.

The specification 1.3,1.3 says that the sort key must starts at field 1 position 3 and ends at the same place.

Comment: As I noted in a comment to the main question, the trouble with this is that `sort` works on a single line at a time, but the data comes in groups of multiple lines (between a line starting with `GI1` and a line starting `ABC123`, for example).